# Fast WebView buttons in ViewPager

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-viewpager

I'm using google's workaround for faster touch response in a WebView as described here https://developers.google.com/mobile/articles/fast_buttons?csw=1
implemented by Alex Black at https://github.com/alexblack/google-fastbutton

Now, the problem is that as soon as I put my WebView in a ViewPager the WebView behaviour is right back to it's original with it's 300ms lag on all touch events.

Actually, what's even stranger is that having my WebView in the first page of the ViewPager it all works as expected. But as soon as the WebView is in page>0 the latency is back.

How can I get the fast buttons to work even when the WebView is in page>0?
Of course I still want the swipe to work for the ViewPager.

UPDATE:
Re-creating the touch handler when selecting a page seems to fix the problem;
myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:reattachMyTouchHandlers()");
But I'm still very interested in an explanation or a cleaner solution.